# File copy action with pull option through jump host

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Get the file in ansible playbook run that is pushed though jump host.

ansible play book run on a host.The host is secured(tier 2) and public domain cannot be accesed, to access public domain there is jump host.

The play book does an set of action on the secured host, need to pull the file in public url . in mid of playbook run need to switch the jump host download the file ,delegate to the target run server and switch back to target server to proceed.

But as the target host is accessed by jump host and not the jump host is reachable though target host.

```
# .........
# .......setup code
# ..............

        - name: Get file
          block:       
            - name: transfer file to dest
              get_url: 
                url: "{{ public url}" 
                dest: "{{ home_dir }}"
                validate_certs: no

            - name: Move the file jump host to target host
              synchronize: 
                src: "{{ home_dir }}" 
                dest: "{{ home_dir }}"

          delegate_to: "{{ jump_host}}"
          when: tier == 't2'

# ....................
# .............continue  actions in target host
```

If the above step is done manually
1) login to jump host
2) download the file from public url
3) scp to target server from jump host
4) login to target server using ssh from jump host
5) continue the action.

As the target host firewall is not open it can be accessed through jump host. the above code access the jump host from target host which is reverse action.

hence want to do the above step mentioned in manual flow

Comment: So whats your question? What kind of problem you have? Is it throwing any error?

Comment: The playbook runs in host which cannot access the url. The file to be downloaded from url which to be copied the running host through jump host but jump host is not accessible from running host. 
Trying to achieve this. 
Host->jump host-> download -> sync with host. 
But when running it throws ssh cannot be connected as jump host is not accessible. 
So how can we switch the running host to jump host and file pushed to running host.